# Where and how does React Native resolve .android.js and .ios.js files?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

The React Native packager has a feature where it automatically chooses between `*.android.js` and `*.ios.js` files depending on the environment being built for. I'd like to see if the same mechanism can be used for `*.web.js` files as well, allowing a web application to be built in the same repository as well.

I'm trying to figure out how this works and where in the code it's implemented, but I can't seem to find it. Is there a way to just set an ENV variable to `web` and have it work?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a part of `React` framework, it's in your iOS/Android project files.

`iOS/AppDelegate.m` line 34:

```
jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle"];
```

`android/app/src/main/java/com/rn/MainActivity.java` line 24-31:

```
mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
                .setApplication(getApplication())
                .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
                .setJSMainModuleName("index.android")
                .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
                .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
                .build();
```

You can change the setting in [`React-Native` generator](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/42eb5464fd8a65ed84b799de5d4dc225349449be/local-cli), but I think using `Webpack` is the better way if you want pack a `index.web` file.

Comment: The problem is the individual resolutions - in the RN packager, you can have myview.ios.js and myview.android.js files and the correct one will be used according to your bundle. I'd like to extend that to web as well.

Comment: Note: `.setJSMainModuleName` has been renamed to `setJSMainModulePath` as of version 0.55.4